# On opening database record, do not allow to change record by other users (PHP+MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, locking

I am working on a custom MVC application.

Its an ERP system where we need to set restriction that if a record is opened by admin1 then other user (admin2) can view but cannot change the record.

I have read about locking table and about transactions but didn't get much cleared idea.

Can someone give exact idea with some sample code.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "recored opened"? For how long do you want the lock. You can set table or row level locks depending on engine, but it's not clear what you want to achieve. Show your code before asking for it.

Comment: Well, suppose i have a record 'users' and id = '1254' when I opened in a php application it allows me to change. if same time you open that record then application should not allow to change that record. 

Did you get my point ?

Comment: Yeah but you didn't think this over properly. What if I open a user record for edit as admin1, then leave. Will it be locked forever?

Comment: Not for ever, till admin1 updated the record. then admin2 can update.

Comment: You don't get it. It's a lot more complex. This just one example you would have to think of to implement some timeout that removes a forgotten lock. E.g. if admin1 loads the edit page but NEVER saves it just leaves the computer.

Comment: @MarcellFülöp This can be mitigated using timeout. The lock can be a timestamp that can be used to determine when the user locking the record has timed out.

Comment: What if we do as Tarik said in other answer that we can solve like start transaction; run query; commit or rollback ?

Answer (score 1):

Whatever db lock you acquire while the php script is running will be released upon script completion. A workaround is to add a column that will serve as a flag indicating that the record is being updated. Alternatively,  you can use a timestamp that is updated via a trigger when the row is updated. You can then use that timestamp to check if someone else has updated that record.
See http://www.akadia.com/services/ora_update_guide.html examples of concurrency control.

Comment: Yes I was thinking same FLAG thing but I was expected that maybe some other solution we have. But in case of FLAG we need to put flag in all tables which are 100+ or maybe we can handle in a new table where we can store (table, recordid, userid). In this way, we can check if table 'users' and record id '1254' is opened by someone then not allowed to change otherwise make it editable. 

am i right ?

Comment: You may also want to consider Optimistic Concurrency Control: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control. Using lock flags can be tricky as some users can abusively keep records locked out for extended periods of time.